# is there a stream lambda expression for angular2?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, lambda

I want to convert a dictionary to a string using angular2

like: `key1=value1&key2=value2&...`

Is there any way to create like java8 stream action? Or an elegant way?

This is my try:

```
mapToFormParamsString( dict : any) : string{
    var a = [];
    for (var key in dict) {
        if (dict.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            a.push(key+"="+dict[key]);
        }
    }
    return a.join("&");
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to `encodeURIComponent`!

Comment: `Object.keys(dict).map(key => …).join("&")` should get you going.

Comment: `Object.keys(dict).map( k => encodeURIComponent(k) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(dict[k]) ).join("&")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That or `Array#reduce`:

```
mapToFormParamsString( dict : any) : string{
    return Object.keys(dict).reduce(function(rv, key) {
        return rv + "&" + key + "=" + dict[key];
    }, "").substring(1);
}
```

or as you're using TypeScript (or ES2015+):

```
mapToFormParamsString( dict : any) : string{
    return Object.keys(dict).reduce((rv, key) => rv + "&" + key + "=" + dict[key], "").substring(1);
}
```

Like yours, that only processes own property names.

Comment: I think this leaves an `&` at the beginning.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin: Note the `.substring(1)` at the end.

Comment: Ah, good point. Do you really need the `+=` though? `reduce` only cares about the return value.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin: No, I don't, you're right there. (I'd also used `entry` where I meant `key`.)

Comment: For anyone interested in experimenting with ES2015 features (available in TypeScript), you can also write this as: `Object.keys(dict).reduce((rv, key) => \`${rv}&${key}=${dict[key]}\`, "");`

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin: Ah, yes, both TypeScript and ES2015 have arrow functions.

Comment: isn't `+` operator much more expensive than pushing to a queue?

Comment: @EladBenda: Two answers to that: 1. No. :-) and 2. It doesn't matter in the 99.9999999% case anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [$httpParamSerializerJQLike](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike).